# How to remove "label" decorators in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How to remove "**label**" decorators in Zend for each multiple radio form element?

*DisableLoadDefaultDecorators* & *setSeparator* doesn't remove it..

Answer (score 0):

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->addElement('radio', 'radio', array(
    'ignore'   => true,
    'label'     => 'Add new material'
));

$element = $form->getElement('radio');
$element->removeDecorator('label');
```